# How to bypass required user input when rendering a R Markdown document

Tags: r-markdown

I have a R Markdown document, which must call a function that annoyingly requires the user to hit enter to see the next plot.

When I use the Knit button in RStudio, it renders fine with no user input required.

But if I use `rmarkdown::render()`, the rendering will pause and require user input from me before it will finish rendering. How do I bypass this so that it will render without any user input like the Knit button does?

I've tried to find a workaround to put the input as part of the code chunk  so that I don't have to manually input it, but I can't find any way to do that. Any other suggestions?

If you want a minimal example of my problem: try using `rmarkdown::render()` on any .Rmd file with the following code chunk without needing manual user input:

```
fun <- function() a <- readline("enter something")
fun()
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this. But...

If you put the render statement in a file.R

Then call source("file.R") does it work? ReadLines only normally applies if R is in interactive mode.

If that doesn't work, does calling it from R on the command line work?

> R file.R

Comment: source() doesn't work. I'm not sure how to do the second suggestions properly in Windows. `R file.R` in command line opens R in terminal but does nothing.

Comment: Use Rscript file.R in Windows

Comment: @CALUM Polwart Yes, that works.